# Ionic App: Cursor in Text area does not work properly

Tags: android, css, textarea, ionic-framework

In Ionic application for android app (version 4.1.2), i have text area to get message as follows

```
  <span class="input-label">Intro Message</span>
  <textarea ng-model="mail.message" rows="20" placeholder="Compose email"></textarea>
```

When i move the cursor in the textarea's text, it does not move properly.

More importantly, i could not move the cursor to last character. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that this seems to be an opened issue on the ionic framework : http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/textarea-and-input-display-problems/4161/12

I have the exact same issue here with beta-13 and a very simple app created with the cli containing only a textarea : when keyboard is up, you can't click/tap inside the textarea. You need to close manually the keyboard then reposition the caret.

Comment: Oh. Then we could not build an app with text area until they fix it. It must be fixed soon, hopefully. Thanks for pointing me.